# R text mining - Combining paragraphs one after the other without sentences mixing up

Tags: string, r, text

beginner in R and text mining. Using the tm package currently.

I am trying to add the texts of two different documents in a corpora together. 
when I use a statement like

```
 c(corpus.doc[[1]],corpus.doc[[2]])
```

or the paste statement

```
  paste(corpus.doc[[1]],corpus.doc[[2]])
```

I get a result of texts combined for every line.

For example:
if

```
> corpus.doc[[1]] 

He visits very often 
and 
sometimes more

> corpus.doc[[2]]) 

She also 
stays
```

What I get with these statements is something like

```
He visits very often She also
and stays
sometimes more
```

How can I prevent that and instead get

```
He visits very often
and 
sometimes more
She also 
stays
```

Or is there an easy way to combine documents in the R tm package? Thank you in advance!

---

Additional info

---

When I use
    a <- c( corpus.doc[[1]], corpus.doc[[2]], recursive=TRUE)

I get that a becomes a corpus with two documents, so the texts of each of these documents are still not combined. I would like it that

```
a[[1]]
```

gives me the combined text of corpus.doc[[1]] and corpus.doc[[2]].

```
str(corpus.doc)
```

Shows something like this

```
 List of 4270
 $ CREC-2011-01-05-pt1-PgE1-2.htm   :Classes     'PlainTextDocument',   'TextDocument', 
      'character'  atomic [1:74] html head titlecongression record volume  issue  
 head  ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "Author")= chr(0) 
 .. ..- attr(*, "DateTimeStamp")= POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2009-01-17 15:45:25"
 .. ..- attr(*, "Description")= chr(0) 
 . . ..- attr(, "Heading")= chr(0) .. ..- attr(, "ID")= chr "CREC-2011-01-05-pt1-PgE1- 2.htm"
```

And it keeps going on...

Comment: Why not use a text editor to copy and paste the text of one doc into the other? If your example the two docs are ''PlainTextDocument' and   'TextDocument', so should be no problem to edit them in a text editor. Then use that new doc as the input for the tm package. Not a pure R solution, but quick if you just have a small number of documents.

Comment: Yes...I know :) It is just that there more than 7000 of these files (they are speech files), and I want to combine the texts based whether they are by the same speaker.

Answer (score 2):

The help in pkg:tm says there is a c.Corpus function whose default setting for 'recursive' is FALSE but if set to TRUE may result in an "intelligent" merger. If you think copus.doc is a list of corpus-class objects, you might try:

```
c( corpus.doc[[1]], corpus.doc[[2]], recursive=TRUE)
```

... but it is not clear that you really do have "Corpus"-class objects.

```
str(corpus.doc)   # see above
```

So the first element in that very long list is *not* a Corpus-classed object, but rather a PlaintextDocument.

Comment: This creates another corpus with two text documents. What I would like is a single document in the corpus.

Comment: Sorry, cannot respond in a meaningful manner because I do not have enough reputation I guess. I edited my original question to answer your questions.

Comment: I mean, I cannot use the code section in comments, I am a beginner on this board with limited functionality.

Comment: @appletree: You have a suggested edit on this answer; it should be applied to the question instead.

Comment: It is applied to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, how about if you combine your plain text documents in `R` before creating the corpus? For example, if `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt` are plain text files, you can read them into `R` like so

```
a <- readLines(file("C:/Users/X/Desktop/1.txt"))
b <- readLines(file("C:/Users/X/Desktop/2.txt"))
c <- readLines(file("C:/Users/X/Desktop/3.txt"))
```

and then you could combine them, similar to your example above

```
abc <- c(a, b, c)
```

That will stack the documents up in order and preserve line-by-line format in a single data object, as you request. However, if you then make this into a corpus with

```
abc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(abc)) # not what you want
```

then you'll get a corpus with as many documents as lines, which doesn't sound like what you want. Instead what you need to do is combine the text objects like this

```
abc.paste <- paste(a,b,c, collapse=' ') # this is what you want
```

so that the resulting `abc.paste` object is a single line. Then when you make a corpus using

```
abc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(abc.paste))
```

the result will be `A corpus with 1 text document` which you can then analyse with functions in the `tm` package.

It should be straightforward to extend this into a function to efficiently concatenate your 7000+ plain text documents and then make a corpus from the resulting data object. Does that get you any closer to what you want to do?